# Are there any tools that will rework JavaScript to a one var per function form?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a significant amount of JavaScript that I'd like to rework to follow the one-var-declaration-per-function form.  Are there any tools that can do this automatically (and that *won't* mess with other code formatting)?

I realize most minifiers will do this, however I am just aiming changing this one aspect of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem due to your formatting constraints and the way most beautifiers work, but if anything can do it, it would be UglifyJS. Specifically look at the `--lift-vars` section: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#readme